# Linq query to keep only last 3 records of each group

Tags: sql, linq

I need a LINQ query to clean up records form a table. Need to keep only the last 3 records of each group (the most recent in fact) and thus I would like to select older records (in order to delete it after).

Example:

```
Id   Ref   Filename     UploadDate
--------------------------------
 1    1    File01.pdf   2019-05-04
 2    1    File02.msg   2019-05-05
 3    1    File03.xls   2019-05-06
 4    1    File04.doc   2019-05-07
 5    1    File05.ppt   2019-05-08
 6    2    File06.pdf   2019-05-04
 7    2    File07.msg   2019-05-05
 8    2    File08.xls   2019-05-06
 9    3    File09.pdf   2019-05-04
10    3    File10.msg   2019-05-05
11    3    File11.xls   2019-05-06
12    3    File12.doc   2019-05-07
```

Above, 3 group of records (grouped by `Ref`: 1,2,3). For each group, ordered by `UploadDate` I would like to select records but skipping the last 3 of each group.

So I need to select only records below:

```
Id   Ref   Filename     UploadDate
--------------------------------
 1    1    File01.pdf   2019-05-04
 2    1    File02.msg   2019-05-05
 9    3    File09.pdf   2019-05-04
```

**UPDATE**

dvo's answer is correct but in the meantime here is another solution:

```
var docs = Context.Records
            .GroupBy(x => x.Ref)
            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.UploadDate).Skip(3));
```

Comment: What have you tried already and what problems did you experience? You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: are you looking for a SQL Query or C# LINQ expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is worded kind of funky... You say two different things in two different places. *"I would like to select older records (in order to delete it after)"* and then later, *"I would like to select records but skipping the last 3 of each group"*.

---

I made a class called `Record` to test. `Record` has the 4 properties from your table in the question and assumes `UploadDate` is type `DateTime` (in order to easily use `OrderBy`).

I made a test list of `Record` called `Records` and filled it with your sample data. I then made the two LINQ queries:

**A: Take all but the last 3 records**

This groups the list of records by the `Ref` field, then orders each group by `UploadDate DESC` (most recent first). The important part is the `.Take()`: the query is grabbing all `Records` besides the last 3.

```
var groupSkip3 = Records.GroupBy(r => r.Ref)
                        .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadDate)
                        .Take(grp.Count() - 3)
                        .ToList()
                        ).ToList();
```

**B: Take only the last 3 records**

The same grouping and ordering is taking place here. The important part is the `.Skip()`: the query is grabbing all `Records` only the last 3 by Skipping all `Records` until the last 3.

```
var groupTakeLast3 = Records.GroupBy(r => r.Ref)
                        .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadDate)
                        .Skip(grp.Count() - 3)
                        .ToList()
                        ).ToList();
```

In both cases, a `List<List<Record>>` is returned so getting the records means you have to loop through the outer list (of groups) and then loop through the inner list (of records). Here is an example printing it to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-15}{3,-15}", 
                "Id", "Ref", "Filename", "UploadDate"));
foreach (var group in groupSkip3)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach(var record in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-15}{3,-15}", 
            record.Id, record.Ref, record.Filename, record.UploadDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding in my question. Need to take a few days off LOL. The A (Take all but the last 3 records) is what I need. I accepted your answer but I also published another alternative.